# Краш бота на хостинге heroku

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Здраствуйте, недавно захостил телеграмм бота на heroku, но при запуске столкнулся с проблемой описанной в логе:

```
2021-07-28T15:52:52.193817+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to worker@1:Free by user моя почта здесь
2021-07-28T15:52:57.391086+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python Project 2.5.py`
2021-07-28T15:52:58.100628+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-07-28T15:53:00.351983+00:00 app[worker.1]: python: can't open file '/app/Project': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2021-07-28T15:53:00.411248+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 2
2021-07-28T15:53:00.546340+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-07-28T15:53:00.561911+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-07-28T15:53:05.864390+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python Project 2.5.py`
2021-07-28T15:53:06.651120+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-07-28T15:53:09.122941+00:00 app[worker.1]: python: can't open file '/app/Project': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2021-07-28T15:53:09.185417+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 2
2021-07-28T15:53:09.359171+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Не понимаю почему может происходить краш, вот полный путь в папку с ботом C:\Users\Егор\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main version my bot

В Procfile написано следующее:

```
worker: python Project 2.5.py
```

Comment: Так в стеке ошибки написано же `python: can't open file '/app/Project': [Errno 2] No such file or directory `.  Где-то неверно указали путь к  вашему скрипту

Comment: Просто при хостинге, указание пути ни где не нужно, а сам бот и так работает